# Load string via jquery into google map

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, dictionary, refresh

I have two vars in a google map, markers & infoWindowContent I need to update via jquery (ajax/php/mysql db). Is it possible to load variables generated using jquery/ajax and refresh the map?

I can dynamically generate the content for markers using jquery but the google map loads first and then the markers are generated, giving me a blank map.

Ideally I wanted to be able to:

on click event

```
 $.ajax({
     url:'script.php?do=get_accs2&area='+area,
     type:'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
       map_markers = data;
  });//end ajax
```

Refresh google map with new markers

```
initMap();
```

Which reruns the below

```
 <script>
        function initMap() {
            var map;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };

            // Display a map on the page
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            map.setTilt(45);


            // Multiple Markers
            var markers = map_markers;

            // Info Window Content
            var infoWindowContent = [
                ['<div class="info_content">' +
                    '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
                    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        
                '</div>'],

                ['<div class="info_content">' +
                    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
                    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
                '</div>']
            ];

            // Display multiple markers on a map
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

            // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
            for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                bounds.extend(position);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: markers[i][0]
                });

                // Allow each marker to have an info window    
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

                // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }

            // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
            var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                this.setZoom(12);
                google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
            });

        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to call `initMap` in the AJAX callback function once the marker data is available.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'script.php?do=get_accs2&area='+area,
  type:'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    map_markers = data;
    initMap();
});//end ajax
```